# Should I mention collaborators in the job talk abstract?

Tags: job, abstract

I will be giving a job talk and I need to submit an abstract for the research job talk. I was wondering if I should mention my collaborators and their affiliations in the abstract? The only thought that's discouraging me is that the talk is on my PhD work which may go against me because I have 3 years of postdoc experience. So ideally they may expect me to present my most recent work.

Note: it is not research focussed school. It is a teaching and undergrad research focussed state school.

Comment: Why not talk about more recent work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the institution you describe, I would think that experience with collaborative work would be extremely important. At such institutions, students get some of their most important early research experience working with, and often publishing with, the faculty. Your collaborative work in the past also puts you in tough with other people who might be able to come up with ideas for student research.

If the talk you are to give is to (perhaps among others) the hiring committee, then your CV will stand on its own, so you don't need to emphasize things that are already there. But to give the affiliations of your collaborators in an offhand way is fine. "Jonny D from Dartmouth and I developed, ..." has a certain nice ring.

You want to be seen as a person with a lot of ideas and also connected to a lot of ideas and happy to share a lot of ideas...

Answer (score 2):

I think it's good form to mention your collaborators in the abstract if you're talking about joint work.  It's not as completely mandatory as mentioning them in the talk itself, but it's still good form.  Mentioning their affiliations, on the other hand, seems pretty weird to me and is not usual at all.

You're not going to be able to hide what paper your *job talk* is about, somewhere that's thinking of hiring you is going to know your paper list!  It is a bit of a red flag to me that you're thinking you can mislead people hiring you about when your research happened and who it was done with.

(It's perhaps worth noting that sometimes job talks, especially in the last few minutes, touch somewhat on how the work you're focusing on connects to the rest of your research program.  It's not necessary to restrict yourself to a single paper.)

Comment: My intent is NOT to mislead but to focus less on the fact that it's my PhD work. I understand that they would know from my CV anyway but I did not want to highlight it. I liked your idea of spending last few minutes on connecting past research with current research. Thanks.